# How to get current Linux GMT timestamp in java?

Tags: java, timestamp, unix-timestamp, gmt

Other questions are either about UTC timestamp or GMT formatted date.

Someone with hands-on knowledge of SimpleDateFormat, Date etc. could know this on top of his head, I hope.

Comment: I know nothing about Linux and what is special about the Linux GMT timestamp, but you could call the native method using reflection? If it is just differently formatted, you can reformat the current (Java) timestamp using a format string.

Comment: the server uses different timezone i.e. CEST or EST and java app on it is supposed to get GMT timestamp to send to a certain API, so your idea seems not as a solution to me, thanks for trying :-)

Comment: try `JODATIME` Jars.. this jars may help you out. :)

Comment: @VikrantKashyap I know it is possible with Joda, if someone do not post the answer

Comment: Unix (not Linux) timestamps don't vary by time zone - wherever you are, the current timestamp is the number of seconds/milliseconds since midnight GMT on 1 January 1970.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, according to http://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html
UTC and GMT there is no difference caused by daylight saving or whatsoever.

Therefore, correct answer seems to be

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

(returns timestamp in UTC, which seems to be the same as timestamp in GMT)

The confusion was caused by a certain API doc which specifically asked for timestamp in GMT timezone.